# Data recovery RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

If an accidental query has been made to the database hosted on Amazon RDS is it possible to recover the data(incase snapshot is not made for that point)? 
How to sync 2 RDS instances residing in different regions?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html

Comment: Those are two separate questions, and should be asked separately.  You may also find that Stack Overflow is not the most appropriate Stack Exchange site for this topic, since RDS is arguably not directly related to our topic here, which is "progranming" (these questions are about administration).